# Python Minimalmodbus sending value

Tags: python, modbus

I need to control the speed of a VSD via Modbus using Python.
I have all working accept one part and that is to send the speed of the VSD.

If I send this command the motor will start

```
 vsd.write_register(8192 , 2 , 0)
```

And this command will let it stop

```
 vsd.write_register(8192 , 6 , 0)
```

The format of the commands are like this

```
Id  code adrsh adrsl   high   low   crc
01  06   20    00      00     06    02 08
```

The documentation of the VSD shows the commands registers and values as hex
But the Python Library requires Decimal. So if I send simple commands all works 100%.

But when I want to set the speed I have to set the high and the low values.
If I send it a 0x2710 or a 10000 the vsd sends back a error. If I use the tool that came with the VSD and I split the value 100.00 (10000) into its 2 bytes of 27 and 10 then all works fine. How do I send the value to the VSD because 0x2710 does not work.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the functioncode = 6. Then it sends the correct bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but just in case someone get stuck with this:

```
freqValue = 45 #freq of 45hz
convertFactor = 100 #may vary but usually is 10 or 100
registerAddress = 8193 #check the manual but usually is after the start stop register
rtuFreqValue = freqValue * convertFactor
vsd.write_register(registerAddress,rtuFreqValue,0)
```